# Schottky+Capacitor as flyback (snubber) diode

Tags: capacitance, flyback, inductive, schottky

Since de-charged caps momentary act as short circuits, why not use schottky+capacitor (in series), as flywheel solution?
don't they (at least theoretically) store fast energy transitions happening when the magnetic field of coil collapse?

(part numbers/values are irrelevant in the following schematic):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2mcEZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Maybe a high value resistor parallel to cap helps with discharge when the coil is switched off.

Comment: this is not a snubber network and will not work.

Comment: Capacitor will be charged to high voltage and it may break coil insulation.

Comment: 10H - that's a BIG inductor. How much current is flowing? You might want to calculate the energy in the inductor.

Comment: Values are meaningless in the schematic. It's just to show the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

What you've created is, essentially, a boost converter. There's no way for the capacitor to discharge other than leakage paths, so every turn-off event would add another few volts to the capacitor--if you keep switching repeatedly, the capacitor will charge up until the diode breaks down.

Comment: You could add a mention about RCD snubbers, while you're at it, as completeness for OP's last phrase.